# Volume automatically increases on iPod Touch 7th Generation running iOS 15.7.6

Tags: ipod-touch, sound-volume

I am encountering a recurring issue with my iPod 7th Generation wherein the volume automatically raises itself to its maximum level. Despite temporarily resolving the issue by restarting the device, the problem persists and recurs approximately once every week. This problem is predominantly observed while using YouTube, although it can also manifest on other applications. I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations to address this matter.

Comment: I have a good hunch it’s an issue with the physical button.  I have seen this before (on an iPhone) but the volume was being decreased, not increased. I was able to get it fixed by opening up the unit and cleaning the contacts with alcohol.     You might want to start with a backup and reinstall first to rule that out.  Then, if it still persists, look at getting it physically serviced.